# My custom interceptor is not being executed in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, cdi, interceptor

I am writing a small app in Quarkus. I am mostly using the quarkus-hibernate-reactive-rest-data-panache extension. One thing is that it doesn't support a partial search for query params. So for example, when searching for the name of a user, it needs the full name instead just the first couple of characters. I'd like to support that.

Now I've written below annotation:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PartialSearch {
    String value() default "name";
}
```

And implemented it like this:

```
@Priority(1)
@Interceptor
@PartialSearch
public class PartialSearchInterceptor {

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        Log.info("Inside of interceptor");

        try {
            Response originalResponse = (Response) context.proceed();

            PartialSearch partialSearch = context.getMethod().getAnnotation(PartialSearch.class);
            String searchProperty = partialSearch.value();
            String searchTerm = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst(searchProperty);

            if (originalResponse.getEntity() instanceof List<?> originalEntities) {
                List<Object> filteredEntities = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Object entity : originalEntities) {
                    if (matchesSearchCriteria(entity, searchProperty, searchTerm)) {
                        filteredEntities.add(entity);
                    }
                }

                return Response.fromResponse(originalResponse)
                        .entity(filteredEntities)
                        .build();
            }

            return originalResponse;
        } catch (SearchCriteriaException e) {
            Problem problem = new Problem(
                    "https://example.com/problem/invalid-property",
                    "INVALID_SEARCH_PROPERTY",
                    Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode(),
                    e.getMessage(),
                    uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString());

            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(problem).build();
        }

    }

    private boolean matchesSearchCriteria(Object entity, String propertyName, String searchTerm) throws SearchCriteriaException {
        try {
            Field field = entity.getClass().getDeclaredField(propertyName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(entity);

            Log.debug(value);
            Log.debug(searchTerm);

            if (value instanceof String) {
                return ((String) value).contains(searchTerm);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new SearchCriteriaException("Error accessing property '" + propertyName + "': " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static class SearchCriteriaException extends Exception {
        public SearchCriteriaException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the method I am using it one. It's in an interface, because that's how to extension works.

```
@ResourceProperties(path = "/users")
public interface UserResource extends PanacheEntityResource<User, UUID> {

    @PartialSearch("email")
    Uni<List<User>> list(Page page, Sort sort);
}
```

The idea behind the annotation is that it takes the result of the API method, and then does some filtering on the provided property (defaults to 'name').

I added some logging, but when I hit the endpoint I don't see the logs in the Quarkus console and I am getting either an empty response (so the default behaviour of the extension) or a response when I search for the full name.

Does anyone know why the annotation might not be getting executed?

Comment: Not sure if this is the root of the problem, but I would expect an `@Inherited` on `PartialSearch`.

Comment: I added the @Inherited annotation, but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Hm. At first glance, the setup seems correct. Can you [edit] the post and add a [MRE], e.g. in form of a github repository? It would also be helpful if you updated the code to include the `@Inherited` annotation.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question but it looks like you should learn about the Hibernate Search extension: that's the right way, and much more powerful and efficient way to implement such queries.

Comment: Annotations are never inherited on methods (at least in CDI, JAX-RS is different, but the annotation in question is an interceptor binding, so the CDI rules matter here), so `@Inherited` will not make a difference. I don't know anything about REST Data with Panache, but I _guess_ that it generates a class implementing that interface, in which case they probably don't copy the annotations to the generated class (which they should IMHO). I suggest you file a bug / feature request.